# Atualizar Frame Selenium VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, excel-vba

Caros,

Como posso fazer para atualizar um frame com o Selenium no VBA?

Atualizar frame é uma opção que existe ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse em algum frame.

Não posso atualizar a janela toda, somente o frame.

Answer (score 2):

Você não mandou nenhum código, nem esclareceu o navegador, mas creio que isso funcionaria:

```
Dim Oxente As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Oxente.SwitchToFrame "identificador-da-frame" 'Vai para a frame
Oxente.Refresh
Oxente.SwitchToDefaultContent 'Retorna ao principal
```